Ubuntu 24.04 ssh race condition
I'm curious about my ansible playbook and how ssh behaves. With Ubuntu 22 they changed how ssh service is started and thus, how it behaves when you use ListenAdress in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189
So I want to use the "old" behaviour and created two tasks in ansible to achieve that - deactivate the ssh.socket and activate ssh.service.
But I got inconsistent behaviour. I tried again and again with rebuild VMs at Hetzner, sometimes it works well, sometimes I got locked out. My tasks looks like this:
- name: ssh | Use old behaviour
  when: ansible_distribution_version is version('22.04', '>=')
  block:

  - name: ssh | Disable ssh.socket service
    ansible.builtin.systemd_service:
      name: ssh.socket
      state: stopped
      enabled: false
      daemon_reload: true

  - name: ssh | Enable ssh.service service
    ansible.builtin.systemd_service:
      name: ssh.service
      state: started
      enabled: true

When I look into the logs I can see:
systemd[1]: ssh.service: Found left-over process 1119 (sshd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
systemd[1]: ssh.service: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
sshd[2769]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
sshd[2769]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION

But its not happening every run, so anyone having an idea whats going on when it works vs when it not works?
I add the output of netsta -tulpnwhen it worked:
      tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1116/sshd: /usr/sbi

and when it didn't worked.
      tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1108/sshd: /usr/sbi

This was captured before I actually restarted the ssh daemon

The post on discourse.ubuntu.com gives a set of five commands to change sshd from socket back to service. Two of the commands seem to be implemented in your Ansible block, but the other three (removal of files under /etc/systemd/ and a reload of systemd) don't seem to be implemented. Could these missing steps be causing your trouble?  While one of the comments on that post suggests they would not, a following comment contradicts it, suggests they could.

I would think you would want to mask the socket as well.

@SottoVoce both files dosent exist on my machine so I didnt added the tasks for this. I added a daemon reload when disabling ssh.socket but it didnt solved the problem

@user10489 When I mask the ssh.socket service I'nomore allowed to enable the ssh.service, it fails then

@patrick_s when I read between the lines of your ansible and image descriptions, you're creating new virtual servers from an image and running the ansible tasks to provision the newly created virtual servers.  Perhaps the files from the discord post don't exist on your original machine, but what's to prevent them from being created on the newly created virtual machines between the time they're launched and the Ansible tasks are invoked?  IMO you should follow all the steps given in the discord post.

@SottoVoce They dont even exist when the VM is newly created, so I followed all the steps

If you followed all the steps, there should be five tasks in your Ansible block, but your code snippet in your question only shows two.  You cited that discord answer as authoritative, but you don't seem to be following the answer's directions.  This doesn't make sense to me, but I'll leave it to someone else to dig deeper into this issue.
